# How to create tables to maintain users family relation?

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2012, relation, sql-server-2012-express

I am working on a "family dictionary" project. I am creating tables in sql server. I am planning to give permission to user to create family, but I can't trust user. He/She can create multiple families.

What is the way to maintain unique family in sql server for several users ? for example:

```
id    fname    lname    sex    
1     Ashish   Jain      M
2     Neha     Jain      F
3     Sachin   Jain      M
```

How can I relate these all persons to a family? What process should I use to create a unique family in database?

Comment: how about another table of families with a FamilyId column that you can then then set as a foreign key in your sample table above.

Comment: Also, you might want to change `sex` to `gender`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have another table 'Family' with an id.

And then from the first table, there would be a foreign key pointing to the family table.

```
id    fname    lname    sex    familyid
1     Ashish   Jain      M     1
2     Neha     Jain      F     1
3     Sachin   Jain      M     2
```